# ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support при выполнении запроса

Tags: mysql

Привет всем! Помогите обойти ошибку 1235. Есть таблица с такой структурой:

```
id INT| date_created TIMESTAMP
```

id у нас авто-инкрементальное поле.

Мне нужно выбрать все записи, сгруппировав их по дате, т.е., нужно получить вот это:

```
+-------+---------------------+
| id    | date_created        |
+-------+---------------------+
|     2 | 2013-03-07 00:00:00 |
|   999 | 2013-03-10 00:00:00 |
| 11027 | 2013-03-14 00:00:00 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

С этим проблем не возникло:

```
SELECT id,date_created FROM rlt_cabinet_reports GROUP BY date_created;
```

Теперь мне нужно получить выборку, в которую не должна включаться последняя запись, т.е., мне нужно получить такую таблицу:

```
+-------+---------------------+
| id    | date_created        |
+-------+---------------------+
|     2 | 2013-03-07 00:00:00 |
|   999 | 2013-03-10 00:00:00 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Последняя запись всегда должна исключаться из результата запроса. Я делаю такой запрос:

```
SELECT id,date_created FROM rlt_cabinet_reports 
WHERE id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM rlt_cabinet_reports 
    GROUP BY date_created 
    ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1
) GROUP BY date_created
```

и получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Как обойти это ограничение? Можете посоветовать чего-нибудь?)

**upd**://

Предлагать ставить другую версию mysql не нужно. Для этой версии mysql уже много кода написано, и у нас никто вот так просто не возьмет, и не переустановит на продакшне мускуль)

Comment: SQL:

    SELECT id,date_created FROM rlt_cabinet_reports 
    WHERE id<>
    (
      SELECT max(id) 
      FROM rlt_cabinet_reports
    ) GROUP BY date_created

Для случая с автоинкриментом, хоть и не лучшее решение :)

Comment: >Мне нужно выбрать все записи, сгруппировав их по дате

Напомню, что `TIMESTAMP` отличается от `DATE`, что очевидно. Для группировки необходимо воспользоваться функцией [`Date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date). **Но** зачем в запрос включать id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чуть изменил. Т.к. надо ориентировать не на ID, а на дату. Пример посмотреть [можно тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95bd5/8/0)

```
SELECT t1.`id`,t1.`date_created` FROM `rlt_cabinet_reports` t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT `id`, `date_created` 
    FROM `rlt_cabinet_reports`
    GROUP BY `date_created` 
    ORDER BY `date_created` DESC LIMIT 1
) t2 
ON t1.`date_created` != t2.`date_created`
GROUP BY `date_created`
```

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке содержится ответ: Поставить другую версию MySQL либо не использовать LIMIT в подзапросах...

Comment: Не вариант. Еще предложения будут?

Comment: сделать двумя запросами. кстати, а почему IN? запись одна же всегда будет

Comment: @thunder, потому что нужно исключить из выборки записи, у которых date_created = самой последней дате.

Comment: эт я понял, только IN тут нафиг не нужен, при условии, что запись будет всегда одна. о чем собственно и пишут в других комментах/ответах :)