# Error Code: 1235 This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql, sql

Пожалуйсто помагите решить проблему

```
AND changes.`change_date` IN (SELECT cc.change_date FROM bs_case_changes cc WHERE cc.`case_id` = cases.`case_id` 
ORDER BY cc.`change_date` DESC
LIMIT 0,2 
)
```

*Error Code: 1235
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'*

Comment: Вопрос - как дубликат )) Tiko. может эта ссылка поможет ?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/202500/error-1235-42000-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF

Comment: `LIMIT 0,2 ` вынесите за скобку, вроде тоже самое будет. Поидее лимит в подзапросах искажает их смысл(круги Эйлера), так что всё корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Переписывайте IN подзапрос через JOIN с нужным подзапросом. В общем виде:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.col1 IN (SELECT col2 FROM t2 WHERE x);
```

можно переписать как

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM t2 WHERE x) t ON t1.col1=t.col2;
```

Если t2.col2 - уникальный ключ, то DISTINCT не потребуется.
Подробней см [MySQL error 1093 и 1235](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/19.html)